# FB App Requests - redirection to App Center Page vs. App Profile Page

Tags: facebook, apprequests

My iOS app will have an invite function which sends requests to users' App Center > Requests tab. What I want to know is, how do I control whether accepting a request takes my users to the App Profile page or the App Center page? For example, if I only have an App Profile page, is that what will be used? And if I have both an App Profile page and an App Center page, will one take priority over the other, or can I control where the user goes when accepting the invitation/request?

(Since the ultimate purpose for me is to get the user to go to iTunes to get the app, is there a way to get the request to redirect directly to there? I realize I can set up the iTunes store page in the App Center settings, but that requires the App Center page to be active first, I guess.)

Comment: did you find the answer to this yet?